# Подтверждение Y \ N

Tags: c++

Необходимо спрашивать юзера, уверен ли он в количестве потоков, которое ввел

```
while (true) {
        int newThreadCount;
        string choice;
        cout << "Количесво потоков: ";
        cin >> newThreadCount;
        cout << endl;
        if (newThreadCount > boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()*2) {
            cout << "Указанное количество потоков сильно превышает количество ядер процессора, прироста производительности не будет. Продолжить? (y\n)";
            while (true) {
                getline(cin, choice);
                if (choice == "n")
                    break;
                else if (choice == "y")
                    break;  
            }
        }
    }
*Код, выполняемый после подтверждения*
```

Как правильно организовать подтверждение (y\n)? Если ввел `y`, то код должен продолжаться, если `n` - должно повторно спрашивать кол-во потоков, если он ввел не y\n, то должно код должен требовать ввести `y` либо `n`.

Comment: внутренний цикл организуйте в виде отдельной функции. В этом случае все сильно упроститься.

Comment: @KoVadim действительно. Сам до этого не додумался ._.

Comment: При выборе no можно делать `return` или выйти с программы другим способом. Внешний цикл коротко-замкнут - нужно менять, или вовсе убрать, или условие выхода с цикла через newThreadCount прописать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если нужно обязательно ввод в нижнем регистре и именно `y/n` (т.е. `yes` - неверный ввод), то, например, так:

```
bool yes()
{
    string s;
    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "(y/n)? ";
        if (!getline(cin,s,'\n')) return false;
        if (s == "y") return true;
        if (s == "n") return false;
        cout << "Wrong input! ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример из книги Бьерна Страуструпа, но он с количеством попыток - tries

...

```
int tries = 1;
while (tries < 4)
    {
      cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n) ?\n";
      char answer = 0;
      cin >> answer; //считать ответ
      switch (answer)
        {
          case 'y':
              return true;
          case 'n':
              return false;
          default:
              cout<<"Sorry, I don't understand that.\n" ;
              tries = tries + 1;
        }
    }
```